# A mysterious paper of Stallings that was supposed to appear in the Annals

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, soft-question

In Stallings's paper

- Stallings, John, *[Groups with infinite products](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1962-10817-9)*, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. **68** (1962), 388–389.

he briefly discusses how to prove "several generalizations" of Brown's theorem saying that monotone union of open $n$-cells is an open $n$-cell; however, he never formulates a precise statement of what he proves.

For the details, he refers to the paper

- J. Stallings, On a theorem of Brown about the union of open cones, Ann. of Math, (to appear).

But as far as I can tell this paper never appeared.  Does anyone know what happened and what the theorem is?

Comment: in a 1963 Ann. of Math. [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970127) by Stallings that paper is still cited as "to appear", however now without a journal being mentioned.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Thanks for noticing that reference!  I think that the lack of a journal might just be the Annals's style guide -- there are several papers in that bibliography that are "to appear", and none of them specify a journal.

Comment: With regards to the publication of this paper, it looks like the journal may have been... stalling

Comment: I feel the pain. There's more than one of these in category theory from the 70s-80s, announced to appear in JPAA, but which never turned up.